# Is this tree sick and is there something I can do about it?

Tags: trees, tree-care

We have this tree in our front yard and it isn't looking that good.  I am guessing it was put in when our house was built in '64 so it is over 50 years old.  I'd love to be able to save it if something is wrong with it but I know very little about trees.  The very bottom branches have no needles on them and then as you go up the tree the branches become fuller and fuller.

I know some coniferous trees shed their lower limbs but even at the top of this tree it looks like it is losing some needles.  We just moved in the house and I don't know any of this trees history.

Here's some more photos in an album: https://goo.gl/photos/XbW5ADuuSNK93SKY9

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the photographs. Instructions are at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I didn't have a good way to make them smaller so they could be uploaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An arborist who can do an onsite visit is always going to be able to see more than pictures can show.  These are the things I see from the photos:

- no signs of recent grade change which trees don't do well with
- base of the trunk is free of grass which competes for water and nutrients
- closeup of the trunk shows branches that have been cut are healing over which is a sign of good health
- no other trees too close
- no sign the local hydro company has been doing pruning to keep the tree out of their wires
- no signs of holes in the trunk bleeding sap which indicate a insect problem
- the main trunk has split into two leaders about 20' (7 m) up. This can be a problem later.  If a strong wind comes up the tree can split at the union of the two leaders.  The smaller leader could be removed now.

I don't see any cause for concern unless you have noticed a change recently that can't be seen from the pictures.  Keep in mind that older trees like it just the way it is.

You can call in an arborist for an assessment but beyond removing the smaller of the two leaders and taking off some of the lower branches I don't see anything that needs doing.

What you could do is water the tree deeply once every few weeks during the summer and fall. Get a drip hose and leave it on overnight.